# Wildfly 18 - WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=http' are not available

Tags: jboss, port, wildfly, jboss-eap-6, wildfly-18

**I am migrating my jboss eap 6 to wildfly 18 as we are moving our application from java 6 to java 8 . I am new to wildfly 18, while starting the server I am getting below error -**

```
09:22:59,671 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' are not available:
    org.wildfly.network.socket-binding.https; Possible registration points for this capability: 
        /socket-binding-group=*/socket-binding=*
09:22:59,672 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=http' are not available:
    org.wildfly.network.socket-binding.https; Possible registration points for this capability: 
        /socket-binding-group=*/socket-binding=*
09:22:59,678 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.**
09:22:59,698 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 18.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 10.0.0.Final) stopped in 13ms
```

I changed socket bindinfs in standalone.xml file and standalone-ha.xml[Added Socket binding changes in both files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FObDp.png) -

As i copied all these sockets from previous jboss eap 6 files.
Can i get explanation why these different 2 socket bindings needed and also worked in jboss?

What capabilities is it searching for? do i need to add some externals?

**Need suggestions on this .. Do am i missing something in standalone.xml file?  or package in module folder? I am confused, need to solve this issue as soon i can..**
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Have you modified `standalone.xml` at all?  Are you positive that there is not another instance running, perhaps through an IDE or something else?  If you're new to Wildfly why are you setting the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable?

Comment: I am migrating my jboss eap 6 to wildfly 18 as we are moving our application from java 6 to java 8, we maintained a environment variable file where all JAVA_HOME , JBOSS_HOME and JAVA_OPTS are already set. Yes I added data sources and  changes socket binding groups in standalone.xml. Also , My user is not allowed to check which other process is running on 8080 port if its port issue.

Comment: Well, you're having problems with socket binding.  Does it start if you don't do that?  What changes are you making?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62863066/edit) the post with this - comments don't handle code well.

Comment: The `standalone.xml` version starts just fine for me with the changes you gave.  Which one are you having problems with?

Comment: thats only my confusion is, if sockets-bindings are ok then why undertow is not capable of getting those resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this error - https , management-https ports were missing in standalone-ha.xml. We have to sure it should be there in both standalone and standalone-ha xml files.

Answer (score 1):

As @Shrishti Jain mentioned socket-binding for http would have not present in both standalone.xml and standalone-ha.xml which could be one possible reason for the error.

There is an another possibility for the above error.

As the console error log(`'/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=http' are not available`) clearly gives a hint that `http-listener` for listener-name `http` under `subsystem` configuration for `undertow` server with the server name `"default-server"` is not available or not configured properly. The section you have to check is mentioned below

```
<!-- subsystem section for undertow server(subsystem=undertow/server)  -->
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
<!-- server=default-server -->
            <server name="default-server">
<!-- http-listener=http -->
                <http-listener name="http" socket-binding="http-new" max-post-size="6442450944" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" max-post-size="6442450944" security-realm="SSLRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
                 ....
        </subsystem>
```

In the above snippet there are chances where the socket-binding of `"http-new"` might have not configured properly. In the above case the `socket-binding` of `http-new` is not present in  `<socket-binding-group>`

```
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
            ....
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

**NOTE:**
The issue causing listener's socket-binding configuration should exist in both standalone.xml and standalone-ha.xml files